# How to assign alert box's message to a variable in Puppeteer and NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
let a = "";
(async () => {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
 const page = await browser.newPage()
 await page.goto('https://www.google.com/')
 page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
 **a = dialog.message();**
  await dialog.dismiss()
 })
 await page.evaluate(() => alert('This message is inside an alert box'))
 **console.log(a);**
 await browser.close()
})()
```

I want to assign dialog box's message to a variable and access it outside the page.on function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a promise, which will be resolved on the event, and then await that promise.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null
});
let resolve;
var dialogPromise = new Promise(x => resolve = x);
const Page = await browser.newPage();
await Page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
  resolve(dialog.message());
  await dialog.dismiss()
 })
var output = await dialogPromise;
console.log(output);
```